# TSQL Counting with Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, counting

I have a table what counts admited and discharge from ED. This is what the table looks like

[image]

I'm trying to get the total admitted and discharged. Something like

Admitted - 100
Discharge - 200

Is there a way to do that with the NULL values?

Comment: Are the values always `NULL` or `1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
    sum(case when Admitted is null then 0 else Admitted end) Admitted,    
    sum(case when DischargedFromED is null then 0 else DischargedFromED end) as DischargedFromED
from MyMagicalTable;
```

or

```
select
    sum(coalesce(Admitted, 0)) Admitted,
    sum(coalesce(DischargedFromED, 0)) DischargedFromED
from MyMagicalTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `sum()`;

```
select sum(admitted) as admitted, sum(DischargedFromED) as DischargedFromED
from t;
```

Aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values.

If you are concerned about `NULL` values appearing *after* the `sum()`, then use `coalesce()` afterwards:

```
select coalesce(sum(admitted), 0) as admitted,
       coalesce(sum(DischargedFromED), 0) as DischargedFromED
from t;
```

The above assumes that the columns are numeric.  If they are some other type, they need to be converted to numbers.

Comment: `COUNT(Admitted)` and `COUNT(DischargedFromED)` would also work since `COUNT(<expression>)` counts non-null values only.

Comment: It's only safe to ignore null with SUM if you know there's at least one numeric result.  Otherwise, SUM returns null, not 0, which I think is what he wanted for his particular use case.  Could also wrap the entire SUM in a coalesce.  Either way, it should be dealt with.  Count might work, but I wasn't 100% sure his columns were BIT and not INT

Comment: @Josh . . . The OPs sample data has values in both columns, so this is actually a non-issue for the sample data.  As for the types, the very first sentence says "I have a table what counts".  `Bit` is not usually referred to as a "count".  But, these are generally reasonable points anyway, so I elaborated in the answer.